# Fetch data from database in cron_hook

Tags: cron

I made a custom module which runs during cron via de cron_hook.
On installation of the module a database table is installed:

```
  $schema['license_expire'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for license_expire.',
    'fields' => array(
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a user.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0),
      'warned_user' => array(
        'description' => 'User warning',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('uid'),
  );
  return $schema;
```

When the cron runs content is added to the database.
Say uid = 1 and warned_user = 1.

But when I try to fetch this warned_user data in de cron_hook it doesn't return any.

```
function hook_cron() {
//EXPIRE VARIABLES
$expiresMonth = strtotime('+1 month');
$expiresWeek = strtotime('+1 week');
$expired = strtotime('today');

//ALL USERS EXPIRING WITHIN ONE MONTH
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_license')
->propertyCondition('status', COMMERCE_LICENSE_ACTIVE)
->propertyCondition('expires', 0, '<>')
->propertyCondition('expires', $expiresMonth, '<');
$results = $query->execute();

//SEND EMAIL TO USERS
if (!empty($results['commerce_license'])) {
    $license_ids = array_keys($results['commerce_license']);

    //all licenses
    foreach($license_ids as $license_id) {

       //get Uid
       $myUid = db_select('commerce_license','cl')
         ->fields('cl', array('uid'))
         ->condition('license_id', $license_id)
         ->execute()->fetchField();

       //for testing it only works for de admin account  
       if($myUid == 1){
           //get user
           $to = user_load($myUid);

           //get expiring timestamp
           $myExpire = db_select('commerce_license','cl')
             ->fields('cl', array('expires'))
             ->condition('license_id', $license_id)
             ->execute()->fetchField();

           $myDate = date("d-m-Y", $myExpire);

           //get times user is noticed
            $myMessages = db_select('license_expire','le')
            ->fields('le', array('warned_user'))
            ->condition('uid', $myUid)
            ->execute()->fetchField();

           //for some reason the $myMessages value is nothing so watchdog is "myMails = = 1"
           watchdog('license expire', 'myMails = '.$myMessages.' = '.$myUid);

           if($myMessages){do something, but it never does because it can't pull $myMessages value from the db, and it sure is there}
```

The above code does work when I use it in a page.tpl.php file.

I found something about, cron being a [Anonymous user and this could be the problem but the solution offered](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/entityfieldquery-doesnt-work-correctly-in-hook-cron) didn't work for me. What dit I forget/overlook/do wrong?

Comment: Try to use `db_select('license_expire')->fields('warned_user')->condition('uid',1,'=')->execute()->fetchAssoc()`

Comment: Hi jmu, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it out but with no succes. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: 1. did you clear cache after you modified? 2. if you use `$query = db_select('license_expire')->fields('warned_user')->condition('uid',1,'=')->exe‌​cute()->fetchAssoc();`, please add `$myMessages = $query['warned_user']` 3. If none of them works, use `print_r($query)` to see what the `$query` includes

Comment: your query doesn't require any access check. You should check in "recent logs".

Comment: the code jmu gives gives a big error for some reason it is looking for the warned_user table?? And my code doesn't give any recent log message.

As said in my original question the query seems to be right it is working in page.tpl.php when I was testing and it does work in another module.

I changed my original post added the full module code. This might help..

Comment: I found the problem, I was using the same variable names (for example $query) in different modules. Changing these variable names to unique names made it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using the same variable names (for example $query) in different custom modules I build. Changing these variable names to unique names made it work perfectly.