# Why does cron run as an anonymous user?

Tags: 7, users, cron

I ran into an issue recently where my hook_cron function was failing when triggered by cron. The problem was that I was calling EntityFieldQuery, which  does access checks and since cron runs as an anonymous user, the query would to process correctly. Specifically, I was having this issue: [EntityFieldQuery doesn't work correctly in hook_cron](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/entityfieldquery-doesnt-work-correctly-in-hook-cron)

I am trying to understand **why** cron runs as an anonymous user. Cron clears the cache and so has at least some database access. When writing hook_cron functions now, I have to bypass access checks so that they return results as expected. Does anyone understand why this is the intended behaviour?

Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

A cronjob should not have to be run by a specific drupal user. It sounds just like a maintenance task that should run sometimes to do something (send a part of a  mail queue, clear some part of cache or whatever).

In some installs (all of mine, for example) run crons via drush/linux cronjob. `cron_safe_threshold` is set to `0` (never).

> Typical tasks managed by hook_cron() are database maintenance,
>   backups, recalculation of settings or parameters, automated mailing,
>   and retrieving remote data.